# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with payroll instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, superclass

```
class employee(object):
    def __init__(self,employeenumber,name):
        self.employeenumber=employeenumber
        self.name=name
    def printdata(self):
        print self.employeenumber
        print self.name
class payroll(employee):
    def __init__(self,employeenumber,name,salary):
        employee. __init__(employeenumber,name)
        self.salary=salary
    def outdata(self):
        self.printdata()
        print self.salary
class leave(payroll):
    def __init__(self,employeenumber,name,salary,nodays):
        payroll. __init__(employeenumber,name,salary)
        self.nodays=nodays
    def showdata(self):
        self.outdata()
        print self.nodays

emp1=leave(3,"sam",5000,8)
emp1.showdata()
```

Tried using "Super" but was getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/limb.py", line 23, in <module>
    emp1=leave(3,"sam",5000,8)
  File "C:/Python27/limb.py", line 17, in __init__
    payroll. __init__(employeenumber,name,salary)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with payroll instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

It would be great if someone could suggest writing this code with super so that i can understand how it actually functions.

Answer (score 2):

To call the overridden `__init__` method directly on the class, you need to explicitly pass in `self`:

```
class leave(payroll):
    def __init__(self, employeenumber, name, salary, nodays):
        payroll.__init__(self, employeenumber, name, salary)
        self.nodays=nodays
```

because methods looked up on a class are not bound to an instance (since Python cannot know what the instance would be in that case). As such you passed `employeenumber` as the first argument instead, which is not a valid type of object to use as the `self` argument for that method.

Alternatively, use the [`super()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), which produces a bound method (so a method object where `self` has been bound to an instance):

```
class leave(payroll):
    def __init__(self, employeenumber, name, salary, nodays):
        super(leave, self).__init__(employeenumber, name, salary)
        self.nodays=nodays
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class like this:

```
class employee(Thread):
```

instead of this:

```
class employee(object):
```